# Custom colored console prompt using crayon

Tags: r, rstudio, crayon

In R I can create a custom console prompt via:

```
options(prompt = "foo> ")
```

And I can use the **crayon** package to make it a certain color:

```
options(prompt = crayon::blue("foo> "))
```

However, in RStudio, color changes never take effect until the prompt is inactive; i.e. until I hit enter and the current line is replaced with a new prompt.

Like this:

[image]

The *current* console prompt is always yellow. Once I hit enter, a new yellow prompt appears and the previous line moves up and is colored blue.

I do not see this behavior when running R from the command line, the prompt immediately turns blue:

[image]

Is there a way around this in RStudio using **crayon**, or is RStudio short-circuiting the prompt formatting in a way that makes it impossible to fix without a change to the RStudio IDE (meaning I should report a bug/feature request with them)?

Comment: Wouldn't this be because RStudio operates something like client/server (even as free desktop, not RStudio Pro) so in some sense the client is going to be 'behind'? Of just shoot me.

Comment: @Chris That is my suspicion as well, but I'm trying to exhaust all my options before pestering them with a bug/feature request.

Comment: Not sure if this will help determine the bug/feature, but have you seen [watcher](https://github.com/brodieG/watcher)? As a manner of shinying down the pole, following execution...

Comment: just wondering did you get any further with this?